# jquery Gender validation wont work

Tags: jquery

```html
<form id="contact-form" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method=post>
    <p>Gender:</p>
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="gender" id="gender-m" value="male">
        Male
    </label>
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="gender" id="gender-f" value="female">
        Female
    </label>
</form>
```

```js
 function checkgender(){
      var gender = $('#gender').val();
      if ($("#gender:checked").length == 0) {
           $("#gender-result").html('gender requirements.');
           return false;
           alert("this is checkgender");
      };

      //jquery started
      $(document).ready(function () {
           $('#contact-form').submit(checkgender);
      });
 });
```

My intention is simple when I clicked on submit and if the gender wasn't selected show the `#gender-result` but I tried so many way, I still cant get what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$('#gender').val();` is wrong, you need to use `$('input[name="gender"]')` to access radio buttons (`#gender` means select the element with id="gender").

Then add `:checked` to get the selected value : `$('input[name="gender"]:checked').val()`

If `undefined`, show message and return false to prevent form submiting, otherwise, submit form.

Bind the verification on the form submit button or on the form submit event.

```
    function checkgender(){
       $("#gender-result").hide();
          if (undefined == $("input[name='gender']:checked", "#contact-form").val()) {
               $("#gender-result").html('gender requirements.').show();
               return false;          
          }
          return true;
     }

    $("input[type='submit']", "#contact-form").on("click", function (e) {
      return checkgender();
    });
```

Here is a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2ukhsaLy/1/).

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<form id="contact-form" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method=post>
    <p>Gender:</p>
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="gender" id="gender-m" value="male">
        Male
    </label>
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="gender" id="gender-f" value="female">
        Female
    </label>
        <button id="submit">submit</button>
</form>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#submit').click(function(){
        if(! $("#contact-form").find("input[name=gender]:checked").length){
        alert("pleade cheeck")
        return false;
        }

    });
});
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/5p7pwuqy/12/)**

NOTE: don't include document ready inside `checkgender` function

Answer (score 0):

In your submit function you have to validate with below function

```
    $("form").submit(function () {
var validationChecker =checkgender();
 if (validationChecker == 1) {
return false;
}
});


function checkgender() {
    var gender = $('#gender').val();
    if ($("#gender:checked").length == 0) {
        $("#gender-result").html('gender requirements.');
        alert("validation");
        return "1";
    }
    else
    {
                alert("success");
      return "0";
    }

  }
```

**Fiddle**
http://jsfiddle.net/Isakkiraj/t9trx946/